# Laravel isEmpty doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

There is an error in Laravel 5.6 when I try to check is a model empty with isEmpty function.

Model:

```
namespace App\Models\Projectmanagement;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $project = new Projects;
    return view('pages.projectmanagement.projects.edit', [
        'project' => $project,
        'companies' => Company::all(),
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  @if($project->isEmpty())
      @method('PUT')
   @endif
</form>
```

The idea is that I reuse edit.blade view file for creating and updating data, so I need to check if a model is empty to make proper changes in the view file.

But in this case, Laravel 5.6 throws an error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty does not exist. (View: /var/www/resources/views/pages/projects/edit.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to get this is using `Model` `exists` variable.
For example:

```
//Case 1
$project = new Projects;
$project->exists; //Has false

//Case 2
$project = Projects::first();
$project->exists; //Has true
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

isEmpty() is not a valid function on your class.

did you mean to use the php function empty()?

In that case try the following:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  @if(empty($project))
      @method('PUT')
   @endif
</form>
```

Note that empty($project) is less optimised compared to $project === null.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

Do this way

```
$project = Projects::all();
```

$project->isEmpty() will work

This you have init an object for the model not fetching records from model.

```
$project = new Projects;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(!$project->id)
  @method('PUT')
@endif
```

I am using forms the same way - one view for create and update, but not making difference in put/post. And using value="{{old('name', $item->name)}}"
Check here for example: https://github.com/LaraModulus/admin-pages/tree/master/src